# Getting ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, bigcommerce

I am building an app for bigcommerce in python,
using bigcommerce sdk (https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-python)
running on Google App Engine
in when trying to fetch a tocken from bigcommerce getting following error:

```
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~acp-bigcommerce/20161220t174745.397888154524804049/lib/bigcommerce/api.py", line 22, in oauth_fetch_token
    return self.connection.fetch_token(client_secret, code, context, scope, redirect_uri, token_url)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~acp-bigcommerce/20161220t174745.397888154524804049/lib/bigcommerce/connection.py", line 250, in fetch_token
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~acp-bigcommerce/20161220t174745.397888154524804049/lib/bigcommerce/connection.py", line 140, in post
    response = self._run_method('POST', url, data=data, headers=headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~acp-bigcommerce/20161220t174745.397888154524804049/lib/bigcommerce/connection.py", line 72, in _run_method
    return self._session.request(method, url, data=data, timeout=self.timeout, headers=headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~acp-bigcommerce/20161220t174745.397888154524804049/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~acp-bigcommerce/20161220t174745.397888154524804049/lib/requests/sessions.py", line 641, in send
    r.content
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~acp-bigcommerce/20161220t174745.397888154524804049/lib/requests/models.py", line 781, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~acp-bigcommerce/20161220t174745.397888154524804049/lib/requests/models.py", line 706, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(108 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(108 bytes read))
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `requests` in Google App Engine, it's recommended you use `requests_toolbelt` aswell.

You can read more about it [here](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#appengineadapter).

In your code, just use

```
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
appengine.monkeypatch()
```

Comment: This helped for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it:
It appears that requests does not work on app engine so well, but there is a fix:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/compare/master...agfor:master

and this is where i took it from

https://github.com/wooyek/flask-social-blueprint/issues/18

Comment: [Links are great, but not enough](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), you should add some context so that the answer is more of an answer.